# Save button of modal changes the text of current tab as well as previously clicked tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have tabs, that when clicked on their respective edit-icon, opens a modal to edit its content.

The problem I am facing, is, that when one opens the editor of one tab, closes it without saving, and then opens the editor of another, and *then* saves it, it is saved on both the previous one and the current one.

I want it to only save to the currently opened tab, and cancel the changes made when clicking on the close-button.

```js
var boxes = document.querySelector('.boxes');
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var closeModal = document.querySelector('.closeModal');
var save = document.querySelector('.save');

boxes.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('.icon')) {
    var para = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    var textBox = document.querySelector('.textBox');
    textBox.value = para.textContent;
    modal.style.display = "block";
    save.addEventListener('click', () => {
      para.textContent = textBox.value;
      modal.style.display = "none";
    });
    closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
    })
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(73 191 214);
  width: 200px;
}

.box .para {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box .icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
}

.modalContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textBox {
  resize: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #ececec;
}

.save {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(247, 42, 121);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closeModal {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is first text for editing . </p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is second text for editing . </p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is third text for editing . </p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is fourth text for editing . </p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is fifth text for editing . </p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="closeModal"> &times; </span>
    <textarea class="textBox"></textarea>
    <button class="save"> SAVE </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why , you declared variable currentPara and save.addEventListener and closeModal.addEventListener outside of the main event listener boxes.addEventListener . I am beginner in Js that's why i am asking this .

Comment: You must declare the same event listeners only once - you declared the save and close EVERY time you clicked a box.
I made currentPara a global (I could have found another way) to only have ONE reference to the current text you wanted to edit because I needed elsewhere in save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your event handlers out of the click and have a placeholder for the box clicked

```js
const boxes = document.querySelector('.boxes');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.closeModal');
const save = document.querySelector('.save');
const textBox = document.querySelector('.textBox');
let currentPara;
boxes.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('.icon')) {
    currentPara = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    textBox.value = currentPara.textContent;
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})

save.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentPara.textContent = textBox.value;
  modal.style.display = "none";
});
closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(73 191 214);
  width: 200px;
}

.box .para {
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box .icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
}

.modalContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textBox {
  resize: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #ececec;
}

.save {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(247, 42, 121);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closeModal {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is first text for editing.</p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is second text for editing.</p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="para"> This is third text for editing.</p>
    <i class="fas fa-edit icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <span class="closeModal"> &times; </span>
    <textarea class="textBox"></textarea>
    <button class="save"> SAVE </button>
  </div>
</div>
```